# How to use elements of xsd type "inline"

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a type representing some tokens corresponding to colors that can be repeated as many times as desired, or not at all (`colorType`), and an element (`main`) that interleaves any number of occurrences of colors and arbitrary text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="colorType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="red" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="blue" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="main">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="color" type="colorType"/>
        <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

So I can do this:

```
<main>
  <text>Beginning</text>
  <color><red/><blue/></color>
  <text>Middle</text>
  <color><red/></color>
  <text>End</text>
</main>
```

What I'd like to do is this:

```
<main>
  <text>Beginning</text>
  <red/><blue/>
  <text>Middle</text>
  <red/>
  <text>End</text>
</main>
```

In other words, keep `colorType` as a type definition so it can be re-used elsewhere in the schema, but put elements of that type "inline" as part of the definition of the `main` element's content (i.e., remove the need for the "`color`" container).  Eventually, the color types will become complex elements with their own attributes (e.g., "`<red bright="true"/>`").

I'm still learning XSD, so any pointers in the right direction would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the effect I want by using an element group instead of complexType for `colorType`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:group name="colorType">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="red" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="blue" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:group>

  <xs:element name="main">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:group ref="colorType"/>
        <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

The `<xs:group>` is inserted "inline" where it is referenced.